# Removing target-actions for UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIButton that is added to each UITableViewCell (except for 2 cells) in a tableview.
The button's target is the UITableViewController.
I noticed that the app has crashed when the action has been sent to the wrong target. I'm assuming that this is because the target has somehow been deallocated (even though, if the UITableViewController has been deallocated, the buttons should not be visible, and not pressable (and should be deallocated themselves)).

I'm guessing I need to balance the addTarget method, with the removeTarget. Like KVO and retain/release.

But I'm not sure where to do this, because I only have a reference to the button when it is being created and added to the cells, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIButton *extraButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [extraButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];
        [extraButton setTitle:@"Meta" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [extraButton addTarget:self action:@selector(extraButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.accessoryView = extraButton;
    }

    if (indexPath.row == kNoExtraButtonRow) {
        cell.accessoryView.hidden = YES;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryView.hidden = NO;
    }
    //set textlabels etc...
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have subclassed UIButton for this or have subclassed UITableViewCell then you can put the code in there to remove the target action for the button when the cell or button is deallocated.  In the UITableViewCell's dealloc you can call removeTarget on the its button, or in the button's dealloc it could call removeTarget for itself.

Answer (score 3):

It is very unusual to need to do this. What is more likely is that you're incorrectly managing memory some other way. In particular, the target of a `UIButton` should generally be the `UIViewController` that owns that button. In most good designs, the button always has a shorter lifespan than the controller. Are you retaining the `UIButton` elsewhere? Are you using a nib file to manage your button, or generating it programmatically? It is somewhat common for people to accidentally create multiple instances of UI elements when they create them programmatically (one of several reasons that nib files are preferred).

Are you sure to use accessors for all your ivars (particularly the button in this case)? Direct access to ivars is the most common way developers create duplicate UI elements. Always use accessors (except in init and dealloc).

Comment: Well the cells, are just UITableViewCell not a subclass. The button [should] have a shorter lifespan, I was confused when I got the error. I'm not using a Nib. I am not sure what you mean by accidentally creating multiple instances of UI elements? I have to create multiple instances, because there are multiple cells. I'll add the code to my question.

Comment: Your above code looks correct. You may want to post the actual crash information.

Comment: well the stack trace is quite unhelpful, as it stopped in the `main` method. The Exception was: `-[_UIResizableImage extraButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x29c480`. And this was after the tableview containing the buttons, had gone off the screen (so it was not possible to touch the buttons)

Answer (score 2):

I think it will help

```
[someControl removeTarget:nil 
               action:NULL 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to removeTarget and please make sure that you are setting Target as self. Your code works fine here for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's assumed that the table view cells enter the reuse queue and come back off of it untouched, but as a sanity check, maybe what you want to do is in the case where `( cell != nil )` coming off the dequeue, you want to `removeTarget` and re-establish the target anyway.

Basically do your own inline `-prepareForReuse` in the `( cell != nil )` case and set the whole thing up (except for the actual table cell alloc) in every case.

Comment: sorry I don't quite understand. I should move the button code outside the if statement? If I do that, then I'll get multiple buttons on each cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [extraButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(extraButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: I know how to remove it, I need to know where to put this line.

Answer (score -1):

Try This.

```
     if (cell == nil){

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]retain];
    UIButton *extraButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]retain];
    [extraButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];
    [extraButton setTitle:@"Meta" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [extraButton addTarget:self action:@selector(extraButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryView = extraButton;
}
```

remove autorelease and add retain in Tableviewcell allocation and in buton allocation.....

Comment: But this will create leaks, quite a lot of them.

Comment: Ok... I think in your extraButtonPressed: method , you check (id) of the sender button. just do one thing, asign tags to button and in method check that tags with button id. i think in that way you got where you got unrecognized selector error.....